# Print Issue: Power BI reports are cutting off in Mozilla and Chrome during print

Tags: printing, powerbi, report

There is a print issue in Power BI reports. The dashboard is cutting off from the right side with the default settings. The dashboard data is dynamically coming in the iframe. Is there any solution.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to export the report into PDF and print?

Comment: yes, I am exporting to pdf and took the print but nothing works.

Comment: I have added one more image while taking the print to pdf

Comment: When we print a report or dashboard in Power BI Service, things like scaling, margins, orientation, size are not controlled by Power BI. The issue is related to browser itself.

In your scenario, to workaround the issue, you can use the Google Chrome browser to print the report, check Custom for Margins, then you can adjust margins to make proper rendering.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and i exported dashboard into PDF and took the print, Absolutely perfect print.

When we print a report or dashboard in Power BI, like scaling, margins, orientation, size are not controlled by Power BI services.
**The issue is related to browser itself.**

In your scenario, i feel, to workaround the issue, you can use the Google Chrome browser to print the report, check Custom for Margins, then you can adjust margins to make proper rendering.

Try as per below screenshots and you can check change Layout and scale

[image]

[image]

Comment: we are using the same workaround but still cutting off in print.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, I realize the print was 50% cutted.

so.... my canvas size in powerbi was from 800px x 1300 px.

Keeping the ratio of my canvas (8/13), I resize the canvas to 1200px x 1950px.

In your powerbi will see the big canvas and empty space to right and bottom, but in the printing you will get the results as you expected.